# How to add cookies(Header) in Android video view to support the older versions of android atleast till jellybean

Tags: java, android, cookies

I have a activity which have `VideoView` to play the videos.

I was simply setting uri to `videoview` like below.

```
 videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
```

After some searching i found the below alternative which can take header values

```
videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri,headers);
```

Here **headers** is `HashMap` which has cookies added.

But As mentioned in this url http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#setVideoURI(android.net.Uri, java.util.Map)

this new method is added in api 21 as it wont support in older versions. Is there any way to support this feature in older versions. Kindly help.

Need for this is basically i need to send some session cookies to `videoview` which needed to play the video.

Kindly note this is my first question in stackoverflow. Please let me know if you need any information to get more idea on this issue.

Comment: So far i did not get any working solution for this. Plz help if someone have any workaround for this.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score -1):

Im not sure but i would suggest something like this:

```
    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(videoView.getContext());
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
    cookieManager.setCookie(videoDomainURL, cookie_value);
    CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
    videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
```